# Can Siebel be automated using Selenium?

Tags: selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [does selenium support testing siebel application?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/does-selenium-support-testing-siebel-application)

I am accessing Siebel using IE browser. Will I be able to automate my functionality in Siebel using Selenium? If yes, could you please let me know how and what are the constraints in it?

Answer (score 2):

No, in my experience automated testing using Siebel not a viable option. This is mostly caused by the ActiveX component Siebel has to install to function properly and to my knowledge Selenium is not to happy about that.

---

A while down the line and I have found Siebel can be automated rather easily using FitNesse and the hsac fixture. It is of course deceptive to put it like this, but for those looking to automate Siebel it is worth looking into.